# Server Real Path

Tags: php

I wonder whether someone may be able to help me please.

I'm trying to retrieve the file path for an xml file that I use to in a image gallery script I'm building.

My folder structure is as follows:

> website/development/UploadedFiles/'username'folder/'location'
>   folder/file.xml

I've put together this to try and get me the path:

```
<?php
chdir('var/www/');
echo realpath('./././file.xml');
?>
```

But I receive the following error:

> Warning: chdir() [function.chdir]: No such file or directory (errno 2)
>   in /homepages/2/d333603417/htdocs/development/real.php on line 2

I'm sure that I'm making a beginners mistake here, but I wanted to have at least given it a try. I just wondered whether someone could possibly take a lok at this please and let me know where I'm going wrong.

Many thanks

Comment: with `./././` you are basically still in the same directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to obtain the absolute path of a file relative to your php file, it is usually easier to do something like `dirname(__FILE__).'/path/to/file'` since it's much more predictable than using chdir with relative paths. You can also just echo it for debugging.

So in your case, it looks like you might want to have something like this:

```
$file = dirname(__FILE__)."/UploadedFiles/$username/$location/file.xml";
```

If you need to traverse directories upwards, you do it with multiple dirnames:

```
$file = dirname(dirname(__FILE__))."/UploadedFiles/$username/$location/file.xml";
```

Comment: Hi @mensi, many thanks for taking the time to help me out. Forgive me for asking a really dumb question, but could you tell me please do I add thsi file to the root and run it from there? Kind regards

Comment: @IRHM it does not matter where the file is, as long as the relative path stays the same and is correct. __FILE__ points to the absolute path of the file this is written in, so adjust the number of dirname's accordingly. This also works with includes, since __FILE__ refers to the actual file it is written in, not the script the webserver originally loaded.

Answer (score 5):

it's because there are 2 types of Unix path's:

absolute path: `/var/www/` (always begins with `/`)

relative path: `var/www/` (relative to the place where you are. has no `/` in the beginning)

If you chdir to `/var/www/` you get to `/var/www/`.

If you chdir to `var/www/` you chdir to `<directory_where_you_are>/var/www/`

Also you have a mistake in `./././`.

`./` - means your current directory. Using `./././` leaves you in current directory.

If you'd like to move up by directory tree use `../` (means parent directory).

Comment: Hi, many thanks for replying to my post. This is really useful to know, especially for a beginner. Kind regards